# PHP Problems with Date Function

Tags: php, sql, debugging, datetime

```
global $adb;                                

$sql = 'SELECT * from vtiger_invoice where invoiceid = ?';
 $result = $adb->pquery($sql,array($_REQUEST['record']));
 $fecha=$adb->query_result($result,$i,'invoicedate'); 

for($i=0;$i<sizeof($vencimientos);$i++)
{
$date[$i] = date_create($fecha);
date_add($date[$i], date_interval_create_from_date_string($periodicidad.' days'));
$fechafinal = explode(" ",$date[$i]->date);
$splitdate = explode("-",$fechafinal[0]);
$reversedate = array_reverse($splitdate);  
 $fechafinal = implode("-",$reversedate);                    

$pdf->MultiCell(100, $summaryCellHeight , $fechafinal, '', 'L', 0, 1, $summaryLineX+135, $summaryLineY);

$summaryLineY += 4;
}
```

The problem is this code dont works, or at least $fechafinal didnt get value. When im debugging, all works 100% but when i execute dont works.

I tried put 'sleeps' but dont works too.

What can i do? This is strange because i cant find error because when im debugging all works :/

Comment: when you say debbugging, what are you doing? where is $i set in this line `$fecha=$adb->query_result($result,$i,'invoicedate'); `

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? What does your schema data look like? And what output/end result are you expecting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem may lie in this line:

```
$fechafinal = explode(" ",$date[$i]->date);
```

A DateTime object doesn't have any public member date so you wouldn't get any string there. What you want to use is format().

With format() You could replace these four lines:

```
$fechafinal = explode(" ",$date[$i]->date);
$splitdate = explode("-",$fechafinal[0]);
$reversedate = array_reverse($splitdate);  
$fechafinal = implode("-",$reversedate);
```

with:

```
$fechafinal = $date[$i]->format('d-m-Y'); // Change the formatting to what you need.
```

Comment: Pfffffffffffffffff.......... that's was amazing guy. Rly rly thanks. This works 100% perfect. Thanks again, u made my day.